apt issue Ubuntu system is not working after uninstall the apt and then install it again
My Ubuntu system is not opening it's happened after i uninstall apt and again installed it.
This below is the error message showing Ubuntu system:-
[ Ok ] Started ACPI event daemon.
[652.642522] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RCM0] (000000009804c00)
[System CMOS] (20210730/evregion-130)
.
.
.
.
[ 1160.901680 ] rtw_8821ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command

So this is the error I am facing since 2 days.
If any body know how to solve it please answer it guys 

That doesn't look like an error message that has anything to do with apt. What else did you do?

please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly. If push comes to shove, re-install - you did have backups of important data of course....
